Difference between たやすい and やさしい
I came across the word たやすい for the first time today. My understanding is that やすい is not generally used as an adjective/noun with the meaning of 'easy' and, in that case, I should use やさしい instead (or maybe 簡単).
Other than to perhaps disambiguate 'easy' and 'kind', what is the difference between たやすい and やさしい?

たやすい (容易い in kanji) and やすい are completely different words (please don't ask me what this た is doing). Compared to やさしい/簡単...

たやすい is simply less common. While it's not particularly old-fashioned or literary, it's not common in real everyday conversations, either. I see this word mainly in fictional stories.
たやすい is a non-gradable adjective that means "a piece of cake" or "extremely easy". Since the meaning of "very" is already integrated in the word, we almost never say "少したやすい" or "どちらがたやすい".
たやすい sounds like you're belittling the task. If you say この問題はたやすかったです to your teacher, it would sound arrogant and rude.


た is prefix with unknown original meaning. Alexander Vovin (2020, page 517) wrote: 「The prefix ta-, like the prefix ka- discussed above, can precede both verbs and inflected adjectives, although, in contrast to ka-, it is attested more frequently with verbs than with inflected adjectives. (...) No definition of its function is given in Japanese scholarship (Yamada 1954: 534). Pierson defined ta- as an intensifying prefix (Pierson 1963: 8). He might be right, although the intensifying meaning is unlikely to fit into most of the examples involving the verb mǝtǝpor- below.」

@Arfrever Do they list other verbs/adjectives with the same prefix-た? I'm curious how they thought it's a prefix when they didn't even know its meaning...

According to Vovin, 「 Similar to the prefix ka- < *kaⁿ-, the underlying form of the prefix ta- is also likely to be *taⁿ-, since this is the form that surfaces consistently before the first obstruent of the following root」. This prefix is attested with these verbs in Western Old Japanese: mǝtǝpor- ("to go around"), mï- ("to turn"), pasir- ("to run"), sar- ("to go away"), sim- ("to grow densely"), wasure- ("to forget"). His examples of adjectives with this prefix: taⁿ-dǝpǝ- (< təpə-), ta-yasu-.

Personally I think (this is not mentioned in Vovin's book) that tapira (modern taira, 平ら) may also have this prefix.

@Arfrever Thank you, looks like ordinary Japanese speakers have completely lost intuition about this. Another word pair similar to this would be 倒れる and 折れる, but I never thought about any connection between them.

Your pair of words look completely unrelated if we check their historical kana spellings in dictionaries: 折れる: おれる (oreru) ← をれる (woreru); 倒れる: たおれる (taoreru) ← たふれる (tafureru (this is a transliteration of kana spelling, not pronunciation at any time in history)). Actual phonetic+grammatical development of ancestor of 倒れる was maybe: /tapuru/ → /tauru/ → /taoru/ (irregular vowel change) → /taoreru/ (regular shift from 二段活用 to 一段活用). So anyway ancestor of 倒れる had /pu/, while ancestor of 折れる had /wo/.

By the way, another word where I have seen this rare あふ /apu/ → あお /ao/ change is 仰ぐ. In most cases /ao/ comes from /apo/ (e.g. 治る) or /awo/ (e.g. 香る, 青い).

Yes, you're absolutely right. I shouldn't have made such careless remarks...


Other than to perhaps disambiguate 'easy' and 'kind', what is the difference between たやすい and やさしい?

FWIW, in my experience, using 「やさしい」 to mean "easy" always came with some confused looks, so I just stuck with 簡単.  There is also [容易]{よう・い}, but it "feels" very 教科書っぽい, and I'd imagine, carries the same connotations that @naruto mentioned.
